# How can I manipulate the following JSON into the desired Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Here is the JSON I am working with:

```js
{
    "2021-05-24": {
        "RSI": "75.1354"
    },
    "2021-05-21": {
        "RSI": "74.5561"
    },
    "2021-05-14": {
        "RSI": "78.1510"
    },
    "2021-05-07": {
        "RSI": "75.3214"
    },
    "2021-04-30": {
        "RSI": "74.1698"
    }
}
```

I need to transform this JSON into the Following Pandas Dataframe:

```
         Date         RSI
0        2021-05-24   75.1354
1        2021-05-21   74.5561
2        2021-05-14   78.1510
...
```

The dataframe that pandas is defaulting to:

```
       2021-05-24       2021-05-21      2021-05-14 
RSI    37.8626          39.4409         40.3654
```

Basically I want to filter the dataframe to exclude RSI Values that are >25 and < 75. If I have the desired dataframe, I can simply filter by the 'RSI' Index. However, I cannot figure out how to filter the current dataframe. Any help is appreciated, and I am pretty new to Pandas.

Comment: df.T  ...transform

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
out = df.T.reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data={
    "2021-05-24": {
        "RSI": "75.1354"
    },
    "2021-05-21": {
        "RSI": "74.5561"
    },
    "2021-05-14": {
        "RSI": "78.1510"
    },
    "2021-05-07": {
        "RSI": "75.3214"
    },
    "2021-04-30": {
        "RSI": "74.1698"
    }
}
```

You can use `DataFrame.from_dict()` method:

```
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data,orient='index')
```

**OR**

Use Transpose attribute:

```
df=pd.Dataframe(data).T
```

**OR**

Use `transpose()` method:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(data).transpose()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.melt()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html?highlight=melt#pandas.DataFrame.melt)

```
df = pd.read_json('<your_file>.json')
df.melt(var_name='Date', value_name='RSI')

        Date      RSI
0 2021-05-24  75.1354
1 2021-05-21  74.5561
2 2021-05-14  78.1510
3 2021-05-07  75.3214
4 2021-04-30  74.1698
```

Or, because your json orientation is `index`, you can set the `orient` parameter of [`pd.read_json()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_json.html) to `"index"`

```
pd.read_json('<your_file>.json', orient='index')

                RSI
2021-04-30  74.1698
2021-05-07  75.3214
2021-05-14  78.1510
2021-05-21  74.5561
2021-05-24  75.1354
```